# hitting a webpage hosted in JBOSS externally

Tags: java, jboss, ip, localhost

I have jboss 5.0 running a web application I am developing. I am able to hit the pages using localhost:8080 but not my external IP address.. How can i hit with my ip???

Comment: http://progrium.com/localtunnel/ ?

Comment: @RC not this.. I am trying to hit the page from another system connected in my LAN specifically giving the ip instead of localhost ex:10.9X.XX.XX:8080..

Comment: http://lorenzod8n.wordpress.com/category/jboss/ might help. (Note: this question is more suited for serverfault)

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the server with additional parameter command with **./run.sh -b 0.0.0.0** or **run.bat -b 0.0.0.0**.

Comment: Ye i tried `run.bat -b 0.0.0.0` against `D:\jboss-5.1.0.GA-jdk6\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin` it is getting started but some deployment errors as well. Where can i see the logs for this???

Comment: @coderman see your jBoss log at D:\jboss-5.1.0.GA-jdk6\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\log\.. directroy

Comment: Ye I am seeing this `2012-08-15 12:07:01,428 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/profile]] (main) Error configuring application listener of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener` but the same error doesnt come up when i start the server via eclipse... Any suggestion??

Comment: BTW i am running a new instance of server not the `default`

Comment: sounds like classpath/build problem

Comment: @Sai Is there any setting in run.bat to set `instance1` instance of `default`..

Comment: @HRgiger Any suggestion??

Comment: @coderman If you use spring 3, add spring-web.jar on your classpath or if you use spring 2x, add spring 2x.jar on your classpath.

Comment: @SaiYeYanNaingAye u want me to include it in run.bat file??

Comment: @coderman No,check this jar is in your application. If it not found, add this jar to your application.

Comment: @Sai Ye it is there.. But i am not running my `default` instance of the server intead i am creating a new `instance1` and running it...

Answer (score 0):

Your router default firewall settings probably doesnt allow tcp/udp connections outside of world to access your local network via port 80 or 8080. You need to set up 'Port Forwarding' on your modem/router. Simply google your **'modem model' port forwarding**. You need to have admin privileges on your modem and if more than one device has connected to your modem/router then you need to make sure you forward your port to correct [DHCP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) .If your DHCP address dynamically assigned you need to make sure you always get same DHCP address per connection. In this case you need to use your [mac address](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-MAC-Address-of-Your-Computer) for creating static dhcp. [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/69612/how-to-set-up-static-dhcp-on-your-dd-wrt-router/) is a one example. Also I would like to inform you opening your ports outside  means anyone can access your ip via this Port which is not secure. I would use a port more than 40000 for the outside then forward to 8080 of local network and access via myIp:40000.

Comment: i am tryin to hit a jboss server in a machine under the same LAN... Still its not getting connected??

Comment: @coderman no this answer not the for local network, I think Sai Ye Yan Naing Aye suggestion is the right answer.